# Laravel BelongsToMany Yielding Nothing

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to get the output of a belongstoMany relationship between `users` and `sections` database, which are tied to `User` and `Section` model, respectively.

User model has this method:

```
public function section()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Section','user_section')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Section model has this method:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User','user_section')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

My user_section table looks like this:

```
+----+---------+------------+------------+------------+
| id | user_id | section_id | created_at | updated_at |
+----+---------+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |       1 |          1 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  2 |       2 |          1 | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+---------+------------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So why when I do this in the business logic:

```
$user = User::where("id",Auth::user()->id)->first(); //user with id of 1 in my case
return json_encode($user->section());
```

Do I get `{}` as output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$user->section()` will return the `BelongsToMany` relationship instead of the model object itself. You can do `$user->section` instead to load the relationship and have the model returned.